# Trouble implementing a deadlock detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, deadlock

I've got it all sorted out except for one specific confusion regarding:

> if Allocation<sub>i</sub> != 0, then Finish[i] := false; otherwise, Finish[i] := true.

Does this mean the *sum* of that particular row is zero or what?

**Algorithm:**

Data Structures:

- Available: A vector of length m indicates the number of available
  resources of each type.
- Allocation: An n x m matrix defines the number of resources of each
  type currently allocated to each process.
- Request: An n x m matrix indicates the current request of each
  process. If Request[i][j] = k, then process P<sub>i</sub> is
  requesting k more instances of resource type R<sub>j</sub>.
- Work: Vector of length m.
- Finish: Vector of length n.

Algorithm:

1. Initialize Work := Available.

   - For i = 1, 2, …, n, if Allocation<sub>i</sub> != 0,
     then Finish[i] := false; otherwise, Finish[i] := true.
2. Find an index i such that both:

   - (a) Finish[i] = false
   - (b) Request<sub>i</sub> <= Work
   - if no such i exists, go to step 4.
3. Work := Work + Allocation<sub>i</sub>

   - Finish[i] := true
   - go to step 2
4. If Finish[i] = false, for some i, 1 <= i...n, then the system is in a deadlock
   state. Moreover, if Finish[i] = false, then process P<sub>i</sub> is deadlocked.
   The less-than-or-equal relation (<=) between two vectors is defined as follows: let X and Y be vectors of length n. We say that X <= Y if and only if x[i] <= y[i] for all i = 1, 2, ..., n. The rows of the Allocation and Request matrices are treated as vectors and are referred to as Allocation<sub>i</sub> and Request<sub>i</sub> in the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Allocation<sub>i</sub> is a vector, "Allocation<sub>i</sub> != 0" means to test Allocation<sub>i</sub> against the zero vector (the vector consisting of all zeros).

In other words, "Allocation<sub>i</sub> == 0" iff every entry in the vector is 0.